# How to transfer emoticons in AngularJs app

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, jboss, utf8mb4

**Framework**

AngularJs

**Database**

MySQL

**Backend**

Jboss

**Error**

My app has a `<textarea></textarea>` for comments from user. AngularJs gets the comment and saves it to MySQL DB. The problem that I am facing is whenever I try to send any emoticons in the text-area, It gets converted to special characters and square boxes with numbers in it.

These are the list of things I tried and failed,

1. Checked my database conf file and made sure that the charset is

> utf8mb4

on both client and server side

2. I have changed the Header of post request to `ContentType:application/json`

Since I have just been introduced to JBoss, Java and MySQL, please let me know If I missed something.

I cannot post the code because it's really large and I am not looking for the exact answer, just some area where I could look into.

I don't think the problem is in Angular part because it is sending the emoticons correctly (please correct me if I am wrong) as can be seen on the console.[image: This is a screenshot of my console when I hit submit button]

**UPDATE**

Details of my MySQL table:

[image]

Screen of one of the comments in db.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: make sure the table has utf8mb4 as the column that records the data, or the default for the table. (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tbsname}`)

Comment: @danblack Yes, my table has utf8mb4.

Comment: @danblack Please, check my question. I have added a screenshot of my console when I hit the submit button.

Comment: Showing `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tblname}` and a `SELECT comment FROM {tblname}` would be useful. After that look what happens in the JBoss/ Java layers.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the reply. I went through my Db, everything seems to have proper settings. I am completely clueless as to why this is happening, any suggestion would be of great help now.

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` != `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Asking 3 times it a bit much. Hide the other columns if you don't want to show them. `SELECT HEX(comment),comment FROM table WHERE ..` might be a good comparison point. SO supports text too, don't have to put things as images.

Comment: Some Emoji need `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.